# Typescript module resolution not working

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

Instead of relative module imports I would like to import my modules like this: `import { IntHelper } from 'utils/IntHelper';`. Even though intellisense works fine in VSCode the transpiled javascript files throw an exception: `Cannot find module`.

**My project structure:**

root

- dist
- src

  - MyProject.ts
  - utils

    - IntHelper.ts
- tsconfig.json

**File: MyProject.ts**

```
import { IntHelper } from 'utils/IntHelper';
```

**File: IntHelper.ts**

```
export module IntHelper {
  export const xy: string = 'Test';
  export function crossSum(int: number) {
    return int; // Nonsense - ofcourse.
  }
}
```

**Tsconfig.json:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
        "*": [
            "*",
            "src/*"
        ]
    }
  }
}
```

**My question:**

Why does it throw the cannot find module exception in the javascript files even though it appears to be fine in the typescript files? When I hover the `'utils/IntHelper'` part in my import line in the typescript file VSCode would also show the correct path to that module.

Comment: What is your builder ? `webpack`, `fusebox`, or are you directly using `tsc` ?

Comment: You could provide `--traceResolution` to typescript compiler in order to see why your module is not resolved. If it is resolved by the compiler, your problem might come from your building solution.

Comment: See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#tracing-module-resolution

Comment: Try `import { IntHelper } from './utils/IntHelper';`

Comment: See answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42197563/typescript2-path-module-resolution

Comment: Is 'export module' NodeJS syntax for exporting stuff?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are having the same problem as many others, the belief that the TypeScript compiler will save the resolved paths to the JS files. That is not the case. You will need to resolve this on your own, or by using a tool, WebPack is often what people suggest (WebPack, however, is a monster), please see this answer:

[Typescript2 path module resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42197563/typescript2-path-module-resolution)

This will most likely solve your problem as well!

Comment: Another option is to use [module-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias). It works on runtime, so it is not needed to run anything. Just import it in the entry point of your code.

Answer (score 2):

Of course in your case node gets confused about the module, because it expects all non-relative paths to be present in node_modules. The good solution with typescript is to use `paths` section of tsconfig like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
        "@utils": [
            "src/utils/*"
        ]
    }
  }
}
```

now we can

```
import { IntHelper } from '@utils/IntHelper';
```

but we still have to notify webpack or node about out path configuration:

```
// for node:
--require tsconfig-paths/register

// for webpack
const TsConfigPathsPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').TsConfigPathsPlugin;


      resolve: {
        plugins: [
          new TsConfigPathsPlugin(),
        ]
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. What resolved it for me was also having to define the aliases in the webpack.config.js file.

```
resolve: {
    alias : {
        alias: {
            "@components": path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/components/"),
            "@constants": path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/constants/"),
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending Patrick_Forseberg's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48246084/10930293) above.

There's no official way of fixing this as mentioned in this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26722), but there is a (very) popular 3rd party npm package called `tsconfig-paths` that fixed my problem perfectly.

All thanks to [eyedean](https://github.com/eyedean) for [mentioning](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26722#issuecomment-501912653) the package.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure inside `ts-config.json`

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
...
    "baseUrl" : "***this path must point to your project directory***"
....
}
```

NOTE: I am currently on node `v14.16.0` and typescript `4.4.2`