# Why is typescript compiler changing my tsconfig.json file on server start up?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to move my react app to a react-typescript app. firstly, this seems really tricky which is disappointing

the issue I'm having is that I get typescript errors in my console. I'm trying to fix them by changing my tsconfig.json file

but whenever I do and restart the server, I get a message in the console saying: `the following changes are being made to your tsconfig.json file`
and then it lists the changes which are basically `"undos"` of the stuff I've just added or changed. why would it do this?

it is a create-react-app project and I followed this to migrate to typescript: `https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-typescript`

Comment: visit and see here... it may help you....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42197563/typescript2-path-module-resolution

Comment: @Jabongg ok cheers I'll check this out. does this allow for gradual migration to typescript?

Comment: it doesn't have many downloads?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because they figured out the problem on their own, with zero information that anyone else will be able to do anything with (they don't explain the problem, they don't mention the versions involved, this post has no reason to hang around)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error eventually went away after upgrading to the latest version of Typescript

Comment: Then why does your post not contain any version information? As is, this question and answer helps no one... not even you, since you figured out the problem on your own.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually add a tsconfig.path.json file with all the compilerOptions included and add "extends": "./tsconfig.path.json" to your tsconfig file.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as the tsconfig file was being overwritten as soon as I run react-scripts. 
I had older react-scripts version 
`"react-scripts": "^2.1.3"`

I changed it to latest version 
`"react-scripts": "^5.0.0"`

And now it doesn't modify the tsconfig.

Answer (score 0):

I have been getting this issue for my React 17 project. Every time I run `npm start`, it overrides whatever I configure in {jsx: ...} with react-jsx in order to be compatible with JSX transform in React 17. And it shows the following message:

> The following changes are being made to your tsconfig.json file:
>
> compilerOptions.jsx must be react-jsx (to support the new JSX
> transform in React 17) The problem is VSCode using an older version of
> typescript (4.0.3), while the typescript version shipped with the
> project is (4.1.2).

**SOLUTION:**

The following did the trick for me:

In visual studio:

- Go to the command palette and press `CTRL+Shift+P`.
- Choose "TypeScript: Select a TypeScript Version...".
- Choose "Use workspace Version".

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Create React App, you can add the following in your `.env` file. Then restart the server. it should work.

```
DISABLE_NEW_JSX_TRANSFORM=true
```

Answer (score -1):

Ejecting from create-react-app worked for me.

Command: `npm run eject`