# Typescript compiler "Cannot find module" on relative import with Gulp/Azure DevOps

Tags: javascript, typescript, azure, gulp

I am trying to build a TypeScript project on Azure DevOps with Gulp.

Compilation fails on /input/InputManager.ts with the following error:

```html
[‌12:27:50‌] Error: TypeScript error: node_modules&#x2F;pm-rflib&#x2F;input&#x2F;inputmanager.ts(1,24): Error TS2307: Cannot find module &#x27;..&#x2F;core&#x27;.‌
    at formatError (C:\npm\prefix\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\versioned\^4.0.0\format-error.js:20:10)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (C:\npm\prefix\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\versioned\^4.0.0\log\events.js:31:15)
    at Gulp.emit (events.js:194:15)
    at Gulp.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
    at Object.error (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\undertaker\lib\helpers\createExtensions.js:61:10)
    at handler (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\now-and-later\lib\map.js:46:14)
    at f (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
    at f (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
    at tryCatch (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\async-done\index.js:24:15)
    at done (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\async-done\index.js:40:12)
```

And the error seems to come from a relative import at the top of that file:

```html
import { Camera } from "../core";
import { PlaneTransform, Point2D } from "../math";
import { Cursor } from "./Cursor";
import { CursorState } from "./CursorState";
import { InputRegion } from "./InputRegion";
import { InputType } from "./InputType";
```

I have verified that the imports starting with "./" seem to import just fine - but imports from the parent folder seem to err.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript2 path module resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42197563/typescript2-path-module-resolution)
See if this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately not a duplicate of this. "Typescript2 path module resolution" describes a scenario where the poster wants to move away from relative paths ("../../foo").
I am not concerned with having to use relative paths. My problem is that relative paths do not compile on Azure, even though they compile fine on desktop.